# Visual Studio Application looking for login.aspx

Tags: asp.net, webforms, visual-studio-2013

I have an asp.net version 4 web application that runs in IIS.  It has worked well, but suddenly is looking for login.aspx.

I don't have and never have had login.aspx in the application.  Why would it look for it now, and how do I fix it?

Comment: your webforms has login page or not ?

Comment: Are you using any validation controls or extenders for any type of ceredentials?

Comment: @zey this site has no login page.  All is available to the visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this site is virtually a child of another site, then that could be the problem.

web.config files have a virtual inheritance hierarchy. The definition of the login page could be coming from a site higher in the virtual hierarchy.

If the higher web.config were to introduce a different login page, then that would affect your site. You would then have to use your web.config to override the changes made in the higher web.config.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure if you've found the answer already but if you don't need authentication in your website then set the authentication mode to none.  Like below

```
<authentication mode="None"/>
```